# How to change "tramp-default-remote-shell" (or any of its descendants)

Tags: emacs27

Whenever I use the `/ssh:` directive and later open a shell (<kbd>M-x</kbd> `shell`) while still looking at the remote file/directory, on the remote end it used to open "/bin/bash" and all I had to do was to remove the current path to that file (point is already conveniently placed).

Fairly recently, however, (possibly with the introduction of v27.1) the suggested shell is "/bin/sh" and I need to additionally change it back manually to "/bin/bash" every time I run it.

While I am the sole user of the computer, I take it that editing "tramp.sh.el.gz" is still not recommended as it may be overwritten by any coming updates.  Is there a way to either change the value for `tramp-default-remote-shell` or any of its derivatives to use "/bin/bash" by the time Emacs has started (user `init.el`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `explicit-shell-file-name` to "/bin/bash".

Comment: That works better than I would hoped.  Not only does it work as outlined, it does not even ask for the path at all anymore.  Great solution!  Danke!